# Routing all packets trough TUN device before forwarding

Tags: kernel, routing

I have an application that creates a TUN device, then checks all packets coming in on that interface and writes them back to the TUN unchanged in case the checks succeed. (Think of a firewall) The source of the packets is the same device on which my firewall application  is running. This machine (VM, `10.0.2.15`) can  reach another machine (Host, `192.168.1.151`) using the main routing table (no setup required). My problem is now, that whenever I send packets via my firewall application the kernel seems to drop them. Specfically, when I run tcpdump on my TUN interface I see the following:

```
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on tun0, link-type RAW (Raw IP), capture size 262144 bytes
12:24:21.548119 IP 10.0.2.15 > 192.168.1.151: ICMP echo request, id 9967, seq 1, length 64
12:24:21.548248 IP 10.0.2.15 > 192.168.1.151: ICMP echo request, id 9967, seq 1, length 64
12:24:22.555972 IP 10.0.2.15 > 192.168.1.151: ICMP echo request, id 9967, seq 2, length 64
12:24:22.556087 IP 10.0.2.15 > 192.168.1.151: ICMP echo request, id 9967, seq 2, length 64
```

You can see that every packet is recorded twice. Once when it goes into my application and once it comes out. However, from there it seems to vanish. Doing a tcpdump on the interface it should go out towards my host doesn't show anything.

I have configured the following on my VM machine:

```
# enable forwarding and disable reverse path filtering
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.default.rp_filter=0
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0
sudo sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1

# routes for the packets to take
sudo ip rule add to 192.168.1.151/32 lookup 11 prio 11
sudo ip rule add iif tun0 lookup main priority 10
```

Table 11 tells the packets to go into my TUN device. This works as shown by tcpdump.

I have also set iptables FORWARD and OUTPUT chains defaults to ACCEPT.
Also, I tested traffic flow using netcat with UDP to exclude problems of packets not finding their way back.

What am I missing? What could be reasons the kernel drops my packets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have an application that creates a TUN device, then checks all packets coming in on that interface and writes them back to the TUN unchanged in case the checks succeed.

> My problem is now, that whenever I send packets via my firewall application the kernel seems to drop them.

The kernel sees packets coming in that it sent out, so it concludes there must be a routing loop somewhere in the network, and to prevent the network from being flooded, drops the packets.

You already tried to disable that behavior with `rp_filter`, but you probably also need to set `accept_local`, because your TUN interface has a local address.

A better approach would be to really use your application as a firewall, have it create two TUN interfaces, one incoming and one outgoing, and move one or both to the network namespace/VM where it is needed.

In that way, you avoid what looks like routing loops.

Comment: ```net.ipv4.conf.enp0s3.accept_local = 1``` did the trick. Thank you!